# How to deselect mat-option in mat-select programmatically if it stay in "active" state and non-clickable

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-table

I have `mat-table`, inside I have `mat-select` with `mat-option`. when I click on it - I invoke `mat-dialog` confirmation modal. when I click cancel (`dialog.close()`) and try again click on last-time-clicked `mat-option` - it stays in "active" state and I can't click it at all.

If I click Yes in `mat-dialog` - so `mat-option` become normal and I can click it again. I think its some trouble with `mat-dialog` because the mat-overlay not trigger some cleanup for buttons Idk, but  ==> how I can remove the `mat-active` state from `mat-option` programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

I solve it by set `deselect()` method on it on click action

```
// inside mat-select
...
<mat-option *ngFor="let option of actionsOptions"
  #opt // <== get local scope of mat-option
  (click)="opt.deselect()"  /* <== user deselect() method to ensure deselecting
                             * within mat-dialog blocking actions.
                             */
  [value]="option.id">
  {{ option.title }}
</mat-option>
...
```

Hope it helps somebody, I've not found info about this case and spent too much time for this simple bug in mat-table with mat-option